# jwt authentication in iOS client nodejs server via third party authenticator

Tags: ios, node.js, authentication, json-web-token

I am trying to wrap my head around using json webtoken (jwt) based authentication on a server coupled to using a third party (say google) to authenticate the user. Originally I've managed to build my own login and jwt handling scheme with `jsonwebtoken` on my `nodejs` server, but we need a client running on an iOS system to interact with it and started looking around for a solution where we don't have to code so much client code (requesting new token when expired etc.) and thought that we would use a third party library to do this for us.

The thing is I did not find anything that would do this for us. I found libraries that could handle connecting the client to a google api for the client, I found user identification handled by google, but didn't find anything that would handle actually getting a `jwt` that the server would except as a genuine user.

My question is essentially this: we have an iOS client and a nodejs server and would like to use google to authenticate our users and have the client call api-s on our nodejs server, with as much of the authentication process handled by some third party library (google's?), how should we get around to this?

As a note, I've seen `passport` but that seems to operate with sessions only, and I would have to solve the jwt handling by myself were I to use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iOS part is not ready, but I managed to use google to authenticate and authorize without a session in the browser. The idea is, that the client logs in to google (see [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) for web app) and google graciously also gives you a token with the login, which will be good for the server. On the `nodejs` side I used `passport` and the `google-id-token` strategy (see on [github](https://github.com/jmreyes/passport-google-id-token)). There are quite a few strategies for google out there, but this one works. Although, this has a shortcoming, it can't accept the token in the header, but I fixed that in a pull request (see [here](https://github.com/jmreyes/passport-google-id-token/pull/16)).

Since I had a bit of a problem of how to use the User.findOrCreate part of all the passport examples, I'll put in my code here that covers a full working example:

```
var passport = require('passport');
var GoogleTokenStrategy = require(passport-google-id-token)

passport.use(new GoogleTokenStrategy({
    clientID: config.googleAuth.clientID,
    clientSecret: config.googleAuth.clientSecret,
  },
  function(parsedToken, googleId, done) {
    console.log(parsedToken);
    console.log(googleId);

      User.findOne({ 'google.id': googleId }, function (err, user) {
          if (!user) {
              var testuser = new User({ 
                name: parsedToken.payload.name,
                givenName : parsedToken.payload.givenName,
                familyName : parsedToken.payload.familyName,
                nameunderscore : parsedToken.payload.name.split(' ').join("_"),

              admin: false,
          email: parsedToken.payload.email,
          settings: {save_folder:"default"},
          'google.id' : googleId,
          'google.email' :  parsedToken.payload.email,
          });
        testuser.save(function(err) {})

        }
        return done(err, user);
      });
  }
));
```

User comes from `mongodb` in a separate `js`:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', new Schema({ 
    name: String,
    nameunderscore : String,
    givenName: String,

    familyName: String,
    admin: Boolean,
    settings: {
        save_folder: String
        },
    email: String,
    google: {
        id: String,
        email: String
        }
}));
```

And this is how I added the `passport` strategy to a router (note that session is set to false):

```
var apiRoutes = express.Router();
apiRoutes.use(passport.authenticate('google-id-token',{ session: false }));
```

Now every call to any route in `apiRoutes` must send on `id_token` with a valid google token to get access.